# Paket won't download logary on install

Tags: mono, paket, logary

Im admittedly a pretty big paket noob.

When I run `mono paket.exe install`

I get

> Paket failed with
>   -> Could not download from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/logary/logary/31e0650902a9c7f92aa90b0b5474a551e6282a7e/src/adapters/Logary.Adapters.EventStore/EventStore.Logary.fs'
>   -> RequestFailedException: Request to 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/logary/logary/31e0650902a9c7f92aa90b0b5474a551e6282a7e/src/adapters/Logary.Adapters.EventStore/EventStore.Logary.fs'
>   failed with: 'NotFound'

However, if you navigate to those links the files download just fine. I'm not sure why it's failing.

Also, even if those files exist already, paket will remove them, then fail to download them once more.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's because the EventStore adapter was upgraded to .Net core and thus unavailable for a while. But it should not be a problem if you had dodged this:

There's a known bug in paket for file dependencies with `paket install` that always downloads the latest file no matter what is in the lock file, unless the file reference is pinned.

So: pin the file, like so: https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave/blob/master/paket.dependencies#L17

```
github logary/logary:c70468f60602e1ab954a38e574b946d4ffbda11d src/Logary.Facade/Facade.fs
```